# Purpose of creating NavigableInterface?

Tags: java, collections, treemap, sortedmap

Why `NavigableMap` interface was created with additional method definitions and extended with `SortedMap`, while they could have added it in `SortedMap` interface and as usual implemented them in `TreeMap`?

The internet is filled with answers that it was included to navigate across the map. Here what does navigate mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `SortedMap` interface is already published (since 1.2). That means that there are maybe hundreds or thousands classes somewhere out there that rely on `SortedMap`. If you would add new methods to `SortedMap` in 1.6, without providing `default` method implementations, this would break all those classes that implement `SortedMap`. Given that so much stuff relies on Java, this would *break literally everything on the planet*. I hope that it is obvious that "not breaking everything on the entire planet" is a good enough reason for not adding some obscure methods willy-nilly *(It's obviously an overly dramatic and tongue-in-cheek description of what would actually happen. If the maintainers of the Java standard library did that, then nobody would use the new version, and someone would probably file a bug report, that's it)*.
2. The documentation states quite clearly what "to navigate" means:

> Methods lowerEntry, floorEntry, ceilingEntry, and higherEntry

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/NavigableMap.html

It means that you can not only lookup and traverse, but also find entries which are "close" to the requested key.

Answer (score 0):

I won't speak to what uses `NavigateMap` has but in terms of why the `SortedMap` interface was not modified instead of adding a new interface; that was because it would break existing implementations. As you point out `TreeMap` etc. could be updated to implement the new methods but what about custom implementations of `SortedMap`? So any legacy code out there that upgrades to JRE 1.6+ would need to search the code base and implement these new methods, but Java advertises itself as being backwards compatible (for Java 6 at least when `NavigateMap` was added)